# How to achieve certain page (url) accessible to certain users

Tags: plugins, user-roles

I have created a download page I want it should be accessible to certain users who are logged in to my blog.
No one else should have direct access to page. Is there some plugin for that?

I have searched a lot but not found any meeting this requirement. Moreover if this possible to create a custom log in page other than wp-admin?

I have tried the password protect option in WordPress visibility but that is not much useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a simple [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) with just five lines of code:

```
/* Template Name: Protected Page */
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
    auth_redirect();
else
    require_once './page.php';
```

Then select that template for the page you want to protect.

`auth_redirect()` will send the user to the login page and back to the original URL after they are logged in.